# VideoJS the play function

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming

I have a problem with the player the point is that when I try to call player.play(); nothing happens. Chrome 72

```js
 var player = videojs('content_video');
 
 player.src({
   src: "https://vdn.terrafox.com/sf/bb-baycam/playlist.m3u8",
   type: "application/x-mpegURL"
 })
 player.ready(() => {
    player.play()
 })
```

```html
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.19/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.19/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.8.0/videojs-contrib-hls.min.js" ></script>  
   
    <video id="content_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" autoplay playsinline width="640" height="360">
    </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you are using (i.e https://vdn.terrafox.com/sf/bb-baycam/playlist.m3u8) is not exist. so play function is not working. If you use proper url for ex. https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8, it will work.

```js
 var player = videojs('content_video');
 
 player.src({
   src: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8",
   type: "application/x-mpegURL"
 })
 player.ready(() => {
    player.play()
 })
```

```html
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.19/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.19/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.8.0/videojs-contrib-hls.min.js" ></script>  
   
    <video id="content_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" autoplay playsinline width="640" height="360">
    </video>
```